# CSS center page with left and right columns

Tags: html, css

I wont to be able to have my main #page in the middle of the page with 2 columns floated left/right of this. I know this would easily work if I re-order the HTML with the left-column first, although I want the #page to come first in the HTML.

HTML:

```
<div id="page"></div>
<div id="left-column"></div>
<div id="right-column"></div>
```

The only way I could think of was to use a 1px transparent div to push the content into the middle, although this is last resort.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EcqXX/7/)

[image]

Comment: Can you please expand on what it is your trying to achive? Its hard to understand...

Comment: @Graeme Leighfield - he wants to keep the current html, but position left-column left, right-column right and have page in the middle column.

Comment: The order of the HTML is VERY IMPORTANT. If you want to have the left column on the left, add it before the page content. Then you can use floats, display: table-cell; or even margin to achieve the effect you desire.

Comment: For SEO purpose I would like to see if this improves rankings if I build the site in the order of importance.

Comment: For SEO, the order of importance for markup isn't really important. The content is the most important thing. Use proper tags in your content and you'll have the SEO thing _down_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wrapper with `display: table;` and the children with `display: table-cell;`
Also the #page element MUST be in the middle. Your markup has to reflect the desired layout of your site, otherwise you'll end up using lots more CSS to complicate things that can be done very simply.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-column">left column</div>
    <div id="page">page</div>
    <div id="right-column">right clomumn</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
 }

#right-column {
        width: 15%;
        height: 500px;
}
#page{ 
        width: 70%;
        height: 500px;
}
#left-colum {
        width: 15%;
        height: 500px;
}

#right-column,
#left-column,
#page
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abwjW/

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov either scroll right in the result window by 1px, or add ´box-sizing: border-box;´ to the ´div´ selector http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/abwjW/13/

Answer (score 1):

```
body {position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;}
#page {margin:0 200px;;background:red;}
#left-column {width:200px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background:green;}
#right-column {width:200px;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;background:blue;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sAC3w/33/

But you cannot use a footer with this since side columns with overlap with absolute positioning.

Comment: This is _nuts_! Why are you using float _and_ position? When you use a float, it effectively positions the element for you, so you only need to use one, or the other. Not both.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - didn't notice - that stayed in from first solution  i tried. Thanks for noticing - it obviously is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you: But you will re-order you HTML so it is left - center - right

```
#wrapper {
        display: table;
}
#right-column {
        width: 15%;
        height: 500px;
}
#page{ 
        width: 70%;
        height: 500px;
}
#left-column {
        width: 15%;
        height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry no this just stacks the div's under each other.

Comment: add float:left to each element.

Comment: I realised that and have edited to improve it. Just add a <div id="wrapper"> around the other html emelemts and it should work

Comment: Then page will be on the left, not centre.

Comment: Centre the wrapper. Margin-auto